# .NET Core 3.1 - Application is shutting down... no explanation why in the console

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I made a .NET Core app, with an angular client

after a while (after 10' ??) the app shuts down automatically

I have no idea what's going on

Here is the error :

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application is shutting down...
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

I expect the app to stay alive in visual studio

I dont really know what code to give to demonstrate the problem

here is the startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<HostOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("HostOptions"));

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddSwaggerDocument();

        // use good old JWT
        var settingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("Settings");
        services.Configure<Settings>(settingsSection);

        var settings = settingsSection.Get<Settings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(settings.JwtSecret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        // Disable authentication and authorization.
        // not yet tested, to test when EC is unavailable
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AllowAnonymousAuthorizationHandler>();

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(o => {
            o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(
                                                            Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDBContext"),
                                                            sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                                            {
                                                                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                                                                maxRetryCount: 10,
                                                                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                                                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                                            })
                                                            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                                                            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
                                                 );

        services.AddDbContext<AppDBContextMysql>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDBContextMysql"))
                                                            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                                                            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
                                                 );

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MemoryBufferThreshold = Int32.MaxValue;
        });

        services.AddScoped<CheckRequestFilter>();

       
        services.AddControllers();
        
        //services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseCors(
                builder => builder.WithOrigins(....)
               .AllowAnyHeader()//WithHeaders("Origin", "Authorization")
               .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS")
               .AllowCredentials()
           );
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseCors(
                builder => builder.WithOrigins(...)
                .AllowAnyHeader()//WithHeaders("Origin", "Authorization")
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS")
                .AllowCredentials()
            );
        }

        app.UseXfo(xfo => xfo.Deny());

        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();    

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
namespace MyApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
        
    }
}
```

thanks for your help
let me know if you need more info

Comment: Post your `Main`. The application is shutting down because `Main` exited. The log entries are emitted by other threads that had to cancel because the process/main thread exits

Comment: press ctrl+e in visual studio and open all of the exceptions to see which one is being thrown

Comment: I added the Main code to the question

Comment: so far CTRL + e opens the interactive shell, I'll wait for the app to crash

Comment: CTRL+E does not do anything...I am already in the output window, there are no exception, the app just shuts down

Comment: Did you figure this out?